# Can Log4j 1.2 What's the difference between RollingFileAppender and FileAppender?

Tags: log4j

How do we know which is the right Appender to use between RollingFileAppender and FileAppender?

Answer (score 13):

You may want to read the [*Apache Log4j 1.2.17 API*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/):

- #### [`org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html)

  > FileAppender appends log events to a file.
- #### [`org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html)

  > RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files when they **reach** a certain **size**.